# Using of verb+ing and to do

Tags: grammar

I wanna explain my confusing in a sentence :
" Do I have to obligate to do this?"
" Do I have to obligate doing this?"
Is there any difference between this sentence? First one I used "to do" and second one I used " doing"
So do they have same meaning? And can I also do this used for others verbs?

Comment: "I want to explain my confusion about a sentence..."

Comment: Your example sentence is very complicated, with four verbs in. It might be better to choose a shorter, simpler, example of what you are trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

"To do" (infinitive) is better than "doing" (gerund) in this case. However, there are a few other changes: "Am I obligated to do this" would be the most natural use of "obligate." "Obligate" is something that happens to you, not something you do—"It rained, so I was obligated to use an umbrella"—the rain forced me to do something. Of course, you could have an even simpler sentence with "Do I have to do this?" since in English "have to" carries the meaning of being compelled.

Comment: Or "Am I obliged to do this?"

Comment: I see. Normally Can i use infinitive  instead of gerund? Maybe you can specify via an example ? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I might have confused things; I meant that "to do this" was better than "doing this." The only way to use "doing" would be in a sentence like "Do I have to be doing this," which changes the meaning a little. "Do I have to eat?" (Is eating something that I must do, in general?) "Do I have to be eating?" (right at this moment).

For your original example, my favorite choice would be "Do I have to do this," for being simple and less formal. "Obliged" has connotations of duty or responsibility, and if you are trying politely to avoid a task, it could sound unintentionally sarcastic.